# How to aggregate the data by filtering it out?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data set something like this:

```
df_A <- tribble(
  ~product_name,    ~position,   ~cat_id,  ~pr,
        "A",             1,          1,    "X", 
        "A",             4,          2,    "X",
        "A",             3,          3,    "X",
        "B",             4,          5,     NA,
        "B",             6,          6,     NA,
        "C",             3,          1,    "Y",
        "C",             5,          2,    "Y",
        "D",             6,          2,    "Z",
        "D",             4,          8,    "Z",
        "D",             3,          9,    "Z",
)
```

Now, I want to look up **1** and **2** in the `cat_id`, and find their position in the `position` for each `product_name`. If there is no **1** or **2** in the `cat_id`, then only these three variable will be returned to NA. Please see my desired data set to get a better understanding:

```
desired <- tribble(
  ~product_name,  ~position_1,  ~position_2,  ~pr,
  "A",                 1,            4,       "X", 
  "B",                 NA,          NA,        NA,
  "C",                 3,            5,       "Y",
  "D",                 NA,           6,       "Z",
)
```

How can I get it?

Comment: Your edit is not reflecting with the examples.  So, not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `filter` the rows based on the 'cat_id', then if some of the 'product_name' are missing, use `complete` to expand the dataset and use `pivot_wider` to reshape into 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df_A %>%
   filter(cat_id %in% 1:2) %>% 
   mutate(cat_id = str_c('position_', cat_id)) %>%
   complete(product_name = unique(df_A$product_name)) %>%        
   pivot_wider(names_from = cat_id, values_from = position) %>%
   select(-`NA`)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  product_name pr    position_1 position_2
#  <chr>        <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 A            X              1          4
#2 B            <NA>          NA         NA
#3 C            Y              3          5
#4 D            Z             NA          6
```

---

Or using `reshape/subset` from `base R`

```
reshape(merge(data.frame(product_name = unique(df_A$product_name)), 
   subset(df_A, cat_id %in% 1:2), all.x = TRUE), 
   idvar = c('product_name', 'pr'), direction = 'wide', timevar = 'cat_id')[-5]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have a quick question: In my real data set, there are more variables. But with your code, these variables also returned to NA. How can I keep them? @akrun